How to identify slabs based on a config table in SQL or excel
I have 2 tables, a Transaction table and Config table.


Based on the percentage achieved, I need to identify slab and rating from the config table.
Config table values can undergo changes including the slabs. So I need to dynamically map.
Can anyone help or provide guidance please.

do you want to return Slab 1 , 0 for first row and Slab 2, 1 for second row?

Yes. @Ryan. that is the expectation

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

you can try this in powerbi
Slab =
IF (
    'Transaction'[percentage] * 100 >= 120,
    "Slab 5",
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            Config,
            'Transaction'[percentage] * 100 >= Config[From]
                && 'Transaction'[percentage] * 100 < [To]
        ),
        Config[Slab]
    )
)

Rating =
MAXX ( FILTER ( Config, 'Transaction'[Slab] = Config[Slab] ), 'Config'[Rating] )



Thanks @Ryan, Although I do not want to hardcode the max threshold which is 120 slab 5, I believe in PowerBI we can get that max value dynamically. This is great learning. Thanks a lot :-).

I can also consider null from TO column for a given region to assign Slab as Slab 5, rather than takin the max or hardcoded value of maximum threshold. Thank you once again.

I think you can use XLOOKUP match mode "next larger item" for this:
Formula in G2:
=XLOOKUP(100*F2,$B$2:$B$5,$C$2:$D$5,HSTACK($C$6,$D$6),1,1)


In Tableau (or equivalently in SQL), you can define a relationship between the Transaction Table and the Config Table, using a three-part (join) condition stating
Transaction.Year = Config.Year AND
Transaction.Percentage >= Config.From AND
Transaction.Percentage <= Config.To

If you config table is properly setup, this will associate each transaction with the corresponding config info. Once the data model defines the relationship, you can then access the config info just as easily as the transaction info.
You'll of course have to make sure the data types and representation of percentages align properly - e.g. use numbers between 0 and 1 instead of strings or numbers between 0 and 100.
In Tableau, and most tools, its often better to encode information common to the schema in the data model rather than in separate calculations.
